# Python: Expanding List of Class Objects

Tags: python, class, attributes, format

this is a quick one. Suppose I got a multidimensional list of class objects, named `table`, and I need to access the class attribute `.name`.

I don't want to use nested loops, and of course to print this, I need to use `format()`.

```
for i in range(3):
    print '{0} - {1} - {2}'.format(*table[i].name)
```

Obviously that didn't work. As well as `(*table[i]).name`. I need to be able to access `.name` for each class object in the `table[i]` list. Mind if you put me to the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to use nested for loops? You'll have to loop through all the elements anyway. You're not saving yourself operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
for row in table:
    print '{0} - {1} - {2}'.format(*[x.name for x in row])
```

Answer (score 4):

[{arg_name.attribute_name}](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) also works:

```
for row in table:
    print(' - '.join('{0.name}'.format(elt) for elt in row))
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to use nested loops

This is silly. To iterate over each element of a multidimensional array, you *need* to use nested loops. They may be implicit (`map` or a list comprehension) but that doesn't mean they're not there! The following is going to be much neater and cleaner than anything with `map` or a nasty `format` unpacking.

```
for row in table:
    for elt in row:
        print <...>
```

---

If you really want to know how to use your method:

```
import operator
for row in table:
    print '{0} - {1} - {2}'.format(*map(operator.attrgetter('name'), row))
```

Tell me that's not messy and unclear compared to the above, not to mention the fact that you've hardcoded in the magic constant 3 -- what if you want to change to a 4x4 table?